# Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^n + n!}{2^n + (n + 1)^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, analysis

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}   \frac{n^n + n!}{2^n + (n + 1)^n}  = 
\lim_{n \to \infty}   \frac{n^n + n!}{2^n + (n \cdot (1 + 1/n))^n} = 
\lim_{n \to \infty}   \frac{n^n + n!}{2^n + n^n \cdot (1 + 1/n)^n}$$

We know that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + 1/n)^n = e$$

So we have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}   \frac{n^n + n!}{2^n + n^n \cdot e}$$

Now we divide by $1/n^n$ and get:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}   \frac{1 + n!/n^n}{2^n/n^n + e}$$

We know $n^n > n!$ and $n^n > 2^n$ for large $n$, so we get
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}   \frac{1 + 0}{0 + e} = \frac{1}{e}$$

Is this correct ? Did I forget something ? Also, do we need to prove that $n^n > 2^n$ or $n^n > n!$ or can I just write what I wrote above ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You evaluated the limit correctly, but your argument has a few flaws:

1. Even though we know that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+ 1/n)^n = \text{e}$, you can't just replace the $ (1+ 1/n)^n$-term in $\lim_{n \to \infty}   \frac{n^n + n!}{2^n + n^n \cdot (1 + 1/n)^n}$  by $\text{e}$ since you're taking the limit for **the whole expression**. Just to show you where that may go wrong: You could erroneously argue that since $\lim_{n \to\infty} 1/n = 0$ we have that $\lim_{n \to\infty}n  = \lim_{n \to\infty} n^2 \cdot (1/n) = \lim_{n \to\infty} n^2 \cdot 0 = 0$, which is obviously wrong.
2. When finally evaluating the limit in your last step, you are not just using that $n^n > n!$ and $n^n > 2^n$ but rather that $n! / n^n$ and $2^n / n^n$ go to zero as $n$ goes to infinity. The reason for those are one-liners:
   $$0 \leq \frac{n!}{n^n} = \underbrace{\frac{n}{n} }_{\leq 1}\underbrace{\frac{n-1}{n} }_{\leq 1} \cdot \ldots \cdot \frac{1}{n} \leq \frac{1}{n} \overset{n \to \infty}{\to} 0, 0 \leq \frac{2^n}{n^n} = \left(\frac{2}{n}\right)^n \overset{n \geq 3}{\leq} \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n \overset{n \to\infty}{\to} 0.$$

In short, first divide by $1/n^n$ in the numerator and denominator such that you have
$$\lim_{n \to\infty} \frac{1 + \frac{n!}{n^n}}{\frac{2^n}{n^n} + \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n}$$
and then, **as each of those limits exists**, we may take the limit for each of the smaller terms:
$$\lim_{n \to\infty} \frac{1 + \frac{n!}{n^n}}{\frac{2^n}{n^n} + \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n} = \frac{1 + 0}{0+ \text{e}} = \text{e}^{-1}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Using Stirling's approximation
$$ n!=\sqrt{2n\pi}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\left(1+\frac1{12n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right) $$
from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation, one has
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
&&\lim_{n \to \infty}   \frac{n^n + n!}{2^n + (n + 1)^n}\\
&=&\lim_{n \to \infty}   \frac{n^n + \sqrt{2n\pi}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\left(1+\frac1{12n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)}{2^n + (n + 1)^n}\\
&=&\lim_{n \to \infty}   \frac{1 + \sqrt{2n\pi}\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)^n\left(1+\frac1{12n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)}{\frac{2^n}{n^n} + \left(1 + \frac1n\right)^n}=\frac1e. 
\end{eqnarray}$$